# Como tornar o meu programa padrão para abrir um tipo de arquivo?

Tags: java, windows

Tenho uma aplicação Java que é bem simples, representa um formulário e, com base no que é digitado em seus `JTextField`, é criado um arquivo chamado "formulario.uniXml". Defini a extensão com este nome já para deixá-la como padrão do meu sistema.

O que quero é: Quando o usuário clicar duas vezes no arquivo com extensão ".uniXml", este arquivo seja aberto pela minha aplicação e o seu conteúdo seja carregado nos `JTextField`s

Agradeço se tiverem algum exemplo ou link de algum tópico aberto existente. obrigado.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao SOpt, seria ótimo se vc nos mostra-se oque já tentou fazer, também sugiro que vc faça um tour para aprender a perguntar:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0592.html

Comment: Boa noite Renan, eu ainda não tentei nada do tipo, até agora consegui converter o meu programa jar para um exe, assim consigo associar o tipo de arquivo .uniXml ao meu software pelo Windows. Porém, quando clico duas vezes num arquivo desse tipo, ele chama meu aplicativo sem carregar o conteúdo do arquivo. O meu arquivo é um xml comum e eu preciso que meu aplicativo funcione com esse xml como o word funciona com um .docx (clico duas vezes no docx e ele abre o word com o conteúdo do arquivo)

Comment: Boa noite galera, há pouco eu vi o link do OnoSendai ai em cima nos comentários. Foi perfeito, era exatamente o que eu precisava. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

## O que é o Java Web Start e como ele é iniciado?

O software Java Web Start permite fazer download de aplicações Java Web e executá-las. O software Java Web Start:

- Permite ativar aplicações facilmente, com apenas um clique.
- Oferece a garantia de que sempre esteja sendo executada a versão mais recente do aplicação.
- Elimina procedimentos complexos de instalação ou atualização.

### Como obter o software Java Web Start

O Java Web Start está incluído no Java Runtime Environment (JRE) desde a release do Java 5.0. Isso significa que durante a instalação do Java, o Java Web Start é instalado automaticamente. O software Java Web Start é inicializado automaticamente quando uma aplicação do Java usando a tecnologia Java Web Start é submetida a download pela primeira vez. O software Java Web Start armazena em cache (armazenamentos) toda a aplicação localmente no seu computador. Portanto, qualquer inicialização subsequente será praticamente instantânea porque todos os recursos exigidos já estão disponíveis localmente. Toda vez que você inicializa uma aplicação, o componente do software Java Web Start verifica o site da aplicação para verificar se uma nova versão está disponível e, caso esteja, faz seu download automaticamente e a inicializa.

### Para inicializar uma aplicação usando o software Java Web Start:

**Em um browser**

Clique em um link de uma página web.

**No ícone da área de trabalho**

Se você usar uma aplicação frequentemente, poderá criar um atalho na sua área de trabalho ou no Menu Iniciar. O Java Web Start pode perguntar se você gostaria de criar atalhos ou uma entrada no Menu Iniciar. Se você responder Sim, todas as inicializações futuras da aplicação poderão começar sem um browser.

**No Viewer do Cache da Aplicação Java**

O Java Web Start também fornece um Viewer do Cache da Aplicação Java que você pode iniciar no Painel de Controle do Java. O viewer do Cache permite que você inicialize diretamente aplicações submetidas a download.

**Instruções para iniciar no Viewer do Cache da Aplicação Java**

1. Acesse Inicializar > Definições > Painel de Controle > Clique duas vezes no ícone Java. O Painel de Controle do Java será inicializado.
2. Clique na guia Geral
3. Clique no botão Exibir na seção Arquivos Temporários de Internet
4. Na lista exibida, clique duas vezes na aplicação que você deseja iniciar.

[image]
<sub>(fonte: [java.com](https://www.java.com/ga/images/pt_BR/5000070701.jpg))</sub>

**No prompt de comando**

Você também pode iniciar uma aplicação por meio de um prompt de comando, digitando javaws jnlp_url, em que jnlp_url é um URL para o arquivo jnlp da aplicação.

1. Vá em Iniciar > Executar > digite command
   Aparecerá uma janela de prompt de comando.
2. Digite javaws url_of_jnlp

### MAIS INFORMAÇÕES TÉCNICAS

[Documentação do Desenvolvedor do Java Web Start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/)

Comment: Mas como isso vai fazer o sistema operacional associar que todos os arquivos com extensão `.uniXml`  deve ser aberto no programa dele?

Comment: 1. Criar um JAR assinado e executável do aplicativo. 2. Criar um JNPL, um arquivo XML que basicamente vai definir como arquivo será executado. 3. Iniciar o programa.

Comment: @guiandmag o que seria um JAR assinado? E como que se faz isso?